# Server 500: Too many pending secure conversations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a fairly simple WCF web sevice, hosted in IIS Express (eventually to be full IIS) using .Net 3.5.  The service method is fairly uninteresting.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MySvc
{
    [OperationContract]
    public Stuff MyMethod(string input)
    {
        Stuff result = DoSomething();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The service configuration is also fairly generic:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MySvcBehavior" name="MySvc">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MySvc">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MySvcBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The service is consumed by a code-behind in an ASPX application.  There's a service reference, leading to some equally uninteresting code.

```
MySvcClient svc = new MySvcClient();
Stuff result = svc.MyMethod("foo");
```

As long as it's one request at a time, everything works just fine and the client code gets the expected result.  Yay.

The problem comes when I do some very primitive stress testing. I load the client ASPX page in a browser, and then hold down the F5 key.  Watching the IIS Express window, at first the results come back as status 200, but after a few minutes I start seeing status 500.  At this point, the service will only respond with status 500 until I restart IIS Express.  (Based on waiting about 10 minutes.)

Setting a breakpoint in the client code, I see the full return message is **"There are too many pending secure conversations on the server. Please retry later."**

Setting a breakpoint in the server code, I find that my code isn't even being invoked.  So it's failing somewhere between the call and the actual start of my code.

My online searches haven't been very promising, mostly leading to the same [suggestion of writing a custom binding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a8f82f1d-e824-474e-84ef-b5e9ba7eca18/) in order to override the maxPendingSessions property and a thread starting with "Someone told me there's a [unnamed] config file setting" which then leads to a broken link claiming Microsoft has acknowledged this as a bug.

The link about the maxPendingSessions property does mention a limit of 128 connections with a timeout of two minutes, and I can certainly see where my method of testing is going to interrupt some connections.  Is this the expected result of an admittedly bad testing methodology? Or can something be done in the configuration to improve this?

Comment: Did you use a `using` statement? The connection will be held open until disposed. Unless there is an `using` statement, cleanup of connections is determined by the garbage collector.

Comment: That is indeed a problem with my client-side code.  But the status 500 messages mean something is unhappy on the server side of the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have a zillion open connections on the server - due to the client side not using a 'using' for the connection.

Comment: I can't argue with that statement. :-)  But since I can't force clients (other than my own) to be well-written, how do I best defend against this problem?

Comment: Sadly, it is basically (unintentionally) a DOS attack (Denial Of Service),   The only way to guard against it would be to drop connections after a period of inactivity.  In your test case, I doubt that would help unless you can actually set the timeout to just a few seconds.

Comment: That's basically the conclusion I'm reaching as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest testing this on full IIS on a server class machine. I wouldn't trust IIS Express on a client OS for performance testing.
 If it is still bad then look at throttling to restrict maxConcurrentCalls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**To those recommending a using statement: You should NOT use a using statement to close clients.**

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Instead to close clients you should use the following snippet:

```
try
{
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
    client.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

Or simply a vanilla catch if you prefer not to cache explicit exceptions. Sometimes you'd want to catch explicit exceptions because if the communication object is not faulted you can retry your operation which offers best use of resources.

To your issue of pending conversations on the server, this will become less common once you close your client correctly, however you may still see it if your server side code has a long running operation and clients are queuing up. In this case, to increase the value of MaxPendingChannels you either have to use a custom binding in both the client and receiver side config files, or programmatically modify the binding on the receiver side before you start the service. The default value of MaxPendingChannels is actually 4 if you are using .NET 3.5. The value is purported to be 128 for .NET 3.0. Both are low in my opinion.

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/745b95d2-1480-4618-89f5-1339d6ee228d

Answer (score 0):

There are too many connections to the targeted server. There are some ways to close the connection in a proper way. Already mentioned is that there should always be an `using` statement around the WCF proxy.

Besides that, there was (is?) a bug that requires you to make a request when opening a proxy. When creating the proxy, it gives the proxy about two minutes the chance to make a request to the server. If it does, it invalidates the timer, allowing cleanup of the proxy. If no request was made, the proxy still waits on the timeout before actually closing the connection. Possibly not the case this time, but added for completeness.

One way to get around this is to make use of (ASP.NET) caching. `System.Web.Caching.Cache` is a nice candidate for this. It allows you to cache results for a given (eventually sliding) period. This way only one request is being made every, say 2 minutes. This makes the website/webservice very scalable. For example, if there are 1000 requests per minute, only one connection was used for the same service call.

Another way to do this, if the request is expensive and not worth waiting for, to make the request in advance and cache the response (ala cron, task scheduler or simply another thread). This will allow pages for fast retrieval.

Other than that, the server should be configured correctly. There is no need to have 128 concurrent connections open from one client. Try to limit this to, say 8 connections per client. This allows multiple clients to be handled at the same time. Also try to set a decent timeout. Waiting for 5 minutes for a client to close its connection, doesn't really increase throughput.

Also consider [asynchronous handling of messages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234085/Fixing-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-API). It uses the time the service has to wait on I/O for handling additional connections. I can't see what the WCF service does, so this might not be relevant.

Comment: Agreed,  these are all good practices for the client.  What I need is a way for the **service** to defend itself against a poorly written client.