# WCF web application crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

We have a WCF web service, let's call him "CrashMan", that is hit tens of thousands times a day by a few other WCF services, and by a website. CrashMan decides to crash every day within a one hour timeframe and the error we start seeing logged from our other services are,

> "CommunicationException during iCrashMan.SomeMethod() 
>   **********************  The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9687500. Increase the timeout value passed
>   to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the
>   Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion
>   of a longer timeout."

To fix the problem, we tried to restart the app pool for CrashMan, which did not help. Then we did a full IIS reset and we started seeing new errors,

> "CommunicationException during iCrashMan.SomeMethod() ********************** Server 'CrashManService' sent back a fault indicating it is too busy to process the request. Please retry later. Please see the inner exception for fault details. ********************** There are too many pending secure conversations on the server. Please retry later. ********************** Stack trace ********************** "

Finally we rebooted the entire server and everything returns to normal.

We can not figure out the problem. It sounds like we are leaving connections open to CrashMan without closing them, but we inspected our code and at first glance, everything seemed fine. Also, once we did a full IIS reset CrashMan clears out all open connections. The IIS reset should have resolved that issue. We also though it might be a DDOS attack, but we have the server that hosts CrashMan whitelisted to only internal IP's.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Any help is appreciatated. Thanks.

**Update:** Here is the code we use to call CrashMan...

```
public List<Attachment> GetAttachments(string accountId)
    {
        ICrashManServiceChannel crashManhannel = ICrashManServiceChannel.CreateChannel();
        List<Attachment> attachments;

        try
        {
            attachments = crashManChannel.GetAttachments(accountId).Select(attachment => new Attachment(attachment)).ToList();
            crashManChannel.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            crashManChannel.Abort();
            return null;
        }

        return attachments;
    }
```

Here is CrashMan's web.config...

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token" >
      <section name="CrashMan.Facade.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <!--KeyValues-->
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--DB connection strings-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="LoggingServiceUrl"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILoggingService"
          contract="LoggingService.ILoggingService" name="WSHttpBinding_ILoggingService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="logging.service@someDomain" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ILoggingService" sendTimeout="00:02:00" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <!--App Settings-->
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="CrmSystemUrl" maxconnection="23" />
            <add address="CrmSystemUrl" maxconnection="23" />
      <add address="InternalLoggingUrl" maxconnection = "25" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection = "2" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you recycling your app pool?

Comment: Do you have an application that has an open using statement?  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841751/server-500-too-many-pending-secure-conversations

Comment: this error means that iis didn't respond in a timely manner so a time out occurred. you need to find out why IIS stopped responding. a few points to check. 1) make sure the maximum number of connection hasn't been reached. 2) make sure that the w3p hosting your service has enough memory. 3) also check if your OS isn't running out of memory 4)other possible causes are that your connection is being disrupted for a short period of time and your not handling the resulting exceptions carefully

Comment: Can you post one or two samples of how you call this service? Also, is it using a session-enabled binding? While at it, include the instancing mode for the service (it's per call if you didn't modify it).

Comment: please list your web.config of crashman, and show how your .NET clients access the service. tens of thousands hits a day is light traffic, there must be some resource/connection leaks somewhere.

Comment: To follow up on the other comments, note that if you do not explicitly close the channel (from the client), you can potentially run out of resources in IIS and see this timeout error.